# Variable defined in Userdefined axis in Jenkins not substituted in Robotframework

Tags: jenkins, robotframework

I'm using Jenkins to run my Robot framework scripts. I have created a multiconfiguration project.

I have the following Configured.

**Under Configuration Matrix**
i have a User-defined axis BROWSER with values Chrome FireFox to run the tests on 2 browsers

**Under BUILDS**
I have given the below shell command
robot --variable BROWSER:$BROWSER TestCases\Newsletter_MultipleData.robot

The issue is that the $BROWSER variable in the shell command is not getting substituted by the User-defined axis values given under configuration matrix. Robot is throwing an error $BROWSER is an invalid browser.

Please guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the below robot CLI command under BUILDS in jenkins to run robot cases in multiple browsers

```
robot --variable BROWSER:%BROWSER% TestCases\*.robot
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the answer, you will be able to mark you answer accepted after 24 hours.

Comment: To accept your answer do click on hollow tick beside the answer it will turn to green on accepting.